# Python List of Lists and List of Dictionaries Troubles

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am attempting to read in two files. A list of questions and a list of students and their answers to those questions. The questions are a list of 50 dictionaries all with default values of 0. There are lists containing dictionaries of 2 keys ie `{This: 0 That:0}`, `{X:0 Y:0}`,...

My job is to read in the students answers to these questions, answer being 0 or 1:

- 0 for option 1
- 1 for option 2

and count up how many times each answer has occurred. Like: `{This: 15 That: 35}`, `{X: 8, Y:42}`

```
def choices_data(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = next(reader)  # get the first row as header
        choices = [dict.fromkeys(set(row), 0) for row in reader]  # initialize with unique keys and 0 values
        choices.insert(0, dict.fromkeys(header, 0))  # add a dictionary with header keys and 0 values at the beginning
    
    return choices
    
def student_data(file_name):
    with open (file_name, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        students = [row for row in reader]
    return students

def count_choices(choices, students):
    name = students[-1][-1]
    students = students[:-1]
    for i in range(len(students[0])):
        choices.append({})
    for row in students:
        for col_idx, element in enumerate(row[:50]):
            if col_idx < len(choices):
                if element in choices[col_idx]:
                    choices[col_idx][element] += 1
                else:
                    choices[col_idx][element] = 1
    return choices, name
```

With my current print, I get

```
This: 0 That: 0
0:35 1:15
X: 0 Y: 0 
0:8 1:42
```

and so on...

Intended result:

```
This: 35 That:15
X: 8 Y: 42
```

I cannot figure out a way to achieve the intended result without appending the dictionary.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think you need to modify the count_choices function to properly count the answers for each question. Iterate over each question in the choices list and count the number of 0s and 1s for each option.

```
def count_choices(choices, students):
    # Get the name of the student from the last row of the students list
    name = students[-1][-1]
    
    # Remove the last row from the students list
    students = students[:-1]
    
    # Iterate over each question in the choices list
    for q in choices:
        # Initialize the count for each option to 0
        q_counts = {k: 0 for k in q}
        
        # Count the number of 0s and 1s for each option
        for row in students:
            answer = row[choices.index(q)]
            q_counts[answer] += 1
        
        # Update the values in the original dictionary
        for k, v in q_counts.items():
            q[k] = v
    
    return choices, name
```

Comment: After a few modifications, I got yours to work. Thank you